# Is there a way to control the verbosity of Dask-YARN logs?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, dask

I'm running a `Dask-Yarn` job on a YARN cluster. After the application finishes, I retrieve the logs of the finished application using YARN CLI and its ID as follows,

```
yarn logs -applicationID {application_id} > out.log
```

The size of `out.log` is in the order of MBs. Upon opening this file, I see a lot of lines dedicated to listing directory contents with the header `LogType:directory.info` which uses up a lot of lines/space. Also, a bunch of environment variable setting. Is there a way to control the verbosity of these logs, either through Dask or Yarn, and limit it to just the logs from what gets evaluated at the workers?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to limit them using,

```
yarn logs -applicationId {application_id} -log_files dask.worker.log
```

to match logs from just the Dask workers.